# amChart4 - Change Top Horizontal Category Color

Tags: amcharts4

I have read all of documentation of amchart, can anyone please guide that how to change color of top horizontal categories text color.

```
    const categoryAxis = subscriberChart.xAxes.push(
      new am4charts.CategoryAxis()
    );
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = 'date';
    categoryAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

    // Create value axis
    const valueAxis = subscriberChart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
    //valueAxis.title.text = 'Place taken';
    valueAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;

    // Configure grid
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color('#0071a5');
    // Configure labels
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#03a9f4');

    // Create series
    const userRegSeries = subscriberChart.series.push(
      new am4charts.LineSeries()
    );
```

https://codepen.io/faiwiz/pen/qBqNawW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to change it is the same as how you changed the value axis' text color - through the `labels` template inside the categoryAxis' `renderer`:

```
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#03a9f4');
```

```js
initChartData = [
    {
      date: '02-06-2021',
      usersReg: 59,
      subscribers: 72,
      subPercent: 69,
      subRenew: 63,
      subCancelled: 45,
      pastDue: 83,
      monthOn: 77,
    },
    {
      date: '02-07-2021',
      usersReg: 30,
      subscribers: 66,
      subPercent: 24,
      subRenew: 61,
      subCancelled: 40,
      pastDue: 41,
      monthOn: 76,
    },
    {
      date: '02-08-2021',
      usersReg: 78,
      subscribers: 24,
      subPercent: 69,
      subRenew: 57,
      subCancelled: 51,
      pastDue: 23,
      monthOn: 61,
    },
    {
      date: '02-09-2021',
      usersReg: 39,
      subscribers: 77,
      subPercent: 17,
      subRenew: 52,
      subCancelled: 53,
      pastDue: 64,
      monthOn: 82,
    },
    {
      date: '02-10-2021',
      usersReg: 29,
      subscribers: 23,
      subPercent: 49,
      subRenew: 26,
      subCancelled: 31,
      pastDue: 28,
      monthOn: 31,
    },
    {
      date: '02-11-2021',
      usersReg: 44,
      subscribers: 33,
      subPercent: 68,
      subRenew: 73,
      subCancelled: 100,
      pastDue: 85,
      monthOn: 95,
    },
    {
      date: '02-12-2021',
      usersReg: 96,
      subscribers: 36,
      subPercent: 84,
      subRenew: 55,
      subCancelled: 48,
      pastDue: 62,
      monthOn: 57,
    },
    {
      date: '02-13-2021',
      usersReg: 62,
      subscribers: 61,
      subPercent: 40,
      subRenew: 91,
      subCancelled: 58,
      pastDue: 83,
      monthOn: 38,
    },
    {
      date: '02-14-2021',
      usersReg: 77,
      subscribers: 62,
      subPercent: 41,
      subRenew: 82,
      subCancelled: 57,
      pastDue: 31,
      monthOn: 15,
    },
    {
      date: '02-15-2021',
      usersReg: 16,
      subscribers: 58,
      subPercent: 87,
      subRenew: 47,
      subCancelled: 83,
      pastDue: 42,
      monthOn: 13,
    },
    {
      date: '02-16-2021',
      usersReg: 97,
      subscribers: 96,
      subPercent: 88,
      subRenew: 36,
      subCancelled: 92,
      pastDue: 95,
      monthOn: 50,
    },
    {
      date: '02-17-2021',
      usersReg: 19,
      subscribers: 78,
      subPercent: 44,
      subRenew: 20,
      subCancelled: 97,
      pastDue: 55,
      monthOn: 57,
    },
    {
      date: '02-18-2021',
      usersReg: 89,
      subscribers: 17,
      subPercent: 70,
      subRenew: 68,
      subCancelled: 55,
      pastDue: 35,
      monthOn: 48,
    },
    {
      date: '02-19-2021',
      usersReg: 58,
      subscribers: 98,
      subPercent: 26,
      subRenew: 34,
      subCancelled: 10,
      pastDue: 61,
      monthOn: 41,
    },
    {
      date: '02-20-2021',
      usersReg: 35,
      subscribers: 94,
      subPercent: 24,
      subRenew: 47,
      subCancelled: 37,
      pastDue: 45,
      monthOn: 72,
    },
    {
      date: '02-21-2021',
      usersReg: 62,
      subscribers: 66,
      subPercent: 42,
      subRenew: 85,
      subCancelled: 12,
      pastDue: 10,
      monthOn: 69,
    },
    {
      date: '02-22-2021',
      usersReg: 38,
      subscribers: 91,
      subPercent: 56,
      subRenew: 80,
      subCancelled: 15,
      pastDue: 42,
      monthOn: 12,
    },
    {
      date: '02-23-2021',
      usersReg: 40,
      subscribers: 76,
      subPercent: 39,
      subRenew: 75,
      subCancelled: 59,
      pastDue: 85,
      monthOn: 91,
    },
    {
      date: '02-24-2021',
      usersReg: 22,
      subscribers: 38,
      subPercent: 44,
      subRenew: 51,
      subCancelled: 86,
      pastDue: 31,
      monthOn: 65,
    },
    {
      date: '02-25-2021',
      usersReg: 43,
      subscribers: 80,
      subPercent: 97,
      subRenew: 52,
      subCancelled: 69,
      pastDue: 20,
      monthOn: 84,
    },
    {
      date: '02-26-2021',
      usersReg: 62,
      subscribers: 34,
      subPercent: 47,
      subRenew: 79,
      subCancelled: 47,
      pastDue: 81,
      monthOn: 77,
    },
    {
      date: '02-27-2021',
      usersReg: 52,
      subscribers: 90,
      subPercent: 57,
      subRenew: 66,
      subCancelled: 44,
      pastDue: 23,
      monthOn: 75,
    },
    {
      date: '02-28-2021',
      usersReg: 16,
      subscribers: 61,
      subPercent: 22,
      subRenew: 63,
      subCancelled: 93,
      pastDue: 99,
      monthOn: 87,
    },
    {
      date: '03-01-2021',
      usersReg: 38,
      subscribers: 44,
      subPercent: 56,
      subRenew: 23,
      subCancelled: 51,
      pastDue: 43,
      monthOn: 85,
    },
    {
      date: '03-02-2021',
      usersReg: 83,
      subscribers: 76,
      subPercent: 15,
      subRenew: 99,
      subCancelled: 93,
      pastDue: 18,
      monthOn: 53,
    },
    {
      date: '03-03-2021',
      usersReg: 96,
      subscribers: 33,
      subPercent: 15,
      subRenew: 45,
      subCancelled: 47,
      pastDue: 47,
      monthOn: 69,
    },
    {
      date: '03-04-2021',
      usersReg: 42,
      subscribers: 25,
      subPercent: 94,
      subRenew: 99,
      subCancelled: 89,
      pastDue: 79,
      monthOn: 33,
    },
    {
      date: '03-05-2021',
      usersReg: 52,
      subscribers: 26,
      subPercent: 16,
      subRenew: 53,
      subCancelled: 52,
      pastDue: 50,
      monthOn: 49,
    },
    {
      date: '03-06-2021',
      usersReg: 94,
      subscribers: 25,
      subPercent: 16,
      subRenew: 65,
      subCancelled: 33,
      pastDue: 86,
      monthOn: 100,
    },
    {
      date: '03-07-2021',
      usersReg: 91,
      subscribers: 29,
      subPercent: 11,
      subRenew: 30,
      subCancelled: 48,
      pastDue: 85,
      monthOn: 56,
    },
    {
      date: '03-08-2021',
      usersReg: 50,
      subscribers: 94,
      subPercent: 87,
      subRenew: 28,
      subCancelled: 48,
      pastDue: 75,
      monthOn: 34,
    },
    {
      date: '03-09-2021',
      usersReg: 30,
      subscribers: 90,
      subPercent: 66,
      subRenew: 78,
      subCancelled: 16,
      pastDue: 90,
      monthOn: 84,
    },
    {
      date: '03-10-2021',
      usersReg: 25,
      subscribers: 62,
      subPercent: 23,
      subRenew: 20,
      subCancelled: 12,
      pastDue: 57,
      monthOn: 38,
    },
    {
      date: '03-11-2021',
      usersReg: 71,
      subscribers: 53,
      subPercent: 32,
      subRenew: 34,
      subCancelled: 81,
      pastDue: 54,
      monthOn: 41,
    },
    {
      date: '03-12-2021',
      usersReg: 31,
      subscribers: 20,
      subPercent: 31,
      subRenew: 82,
      subCancelled: 92,
      pastDue: 38,
      monthOn: 71,
    },
    {
      date: '03-13-2021',
      usersReg: 79,
      subscribers: 77,
      subPercent: 58,
      subRenew: 45,
      subCancelled: 59,
      pastDue: 74,
      monthOn: 22,
    },
    {
      date: '03-14-2021',
      usersReg: 91,
      subscribers: 60,
      subPercent: 96,
      subRenew: 59,
      subCancelled: 40,
      pastDue: 74,
      monthOn: 23,
    },
    {
      date: '03-15-2021',
      usersReg: 100,
      subscribers: 92,
      subPercent: 21,
      subRenew: 22,
      subCancelled: 40,
      pastDue: 62,
      monthOn: 26,
    },
    {
      date: '03-16-2021',
      usersReg: 54,
      subscribers: 78,
      subPercent: 92,
      subRenew: 26,
      subCancelled: 77,
      pastDue: 56,
      monthOn: 77,
    },
    {
      date: '03-17-2021',
      usersReg: 15,
      subscribers: 93,
      subPercent: 26,
      subRenew: 96,
      subCancelled: 31,
      pastDue: 13,
      monthOn: 48,
    },
    {
      date: '03-18-2021',
      usersReg: 49,
      subscribers: 41,
      subPercent: 96,
      subRenew: 35,
      subCancelled: 31,
      pastDue: 78,
      monthOn: 47,
    },
    {
      date: '03-19-2021',
      usersReg: 64,
      subscribers: 73,
      subPercent: 83,
      subRenew: 25,
      subCancelled: 85,
      pastDue: 27,
      monthOn: 39,
    },
    {
      date: '03-20-2021',
      usersReg: 71,
      subscribers: 38,
      subPercent: 66,
      subRenew: 66,
      subCancelled: 89,
      pastDue: 98,
      monthOn: 37,
    },
    {
      date: '03-21-2021',
      usersReg: 100,
      subscribers: 16,
      subPercent: 71,
      subRenew: 73,
      subCancelled: 68,
      pastDue: 96,
      monthOn: 62,
    },
    {
      date: '03-22-2021',
      usersReg: 66,
      subscribers: 18,
      subPercent: 82,
      subRenew: 37,
      subCancelled: 45,
      pastDue: 73,
      monthOn: 88,
    },
    {
      date: '03-23-2021',
      usersReg: 89,
      subscribers: 17,
      subPercent: 86,
      subRenew: 89,
      subCancelled: 68,
      pastDue: 95,
      monthOn: 90,
    },
    {
      date: '03-24-2021',
      usersReg: 74,
      subscribers: 24,
      subPercent: 77,
      subRenew: 89,
      subCancelled: 32,
      pastDue: 88,
      monthOn: 42,
    },
    {
      date: '03-25-2021',
      usersReg: 66,
      subscribers: 18,
      subPercent: 90,
      subRenew: 18,
      subCancelled: 76,
      pastDue: 94,
      monthOn: 83,
    },
    {
      date: '03-26-2021',
      usersReg: 82,
      subscribers: 24,
      subPercent: 44,
      subRenew: 96,
      subCancelled: 37,
      pastDue: 50,
      monthOn: 57,
    },
    {
      date: '03-27-2021',
      usersReg: 62,
      subscribers: 72,
      subPercent: 77,
      subRenew: 51,
      subCancelled: 70,
      pastDue: 31,
      monthOn: 13,
    },
    {
      date: '03-28-2021',
      usersReg: 10,
      subscribers: 15,
      subPercent: 90,
      subRenew: 71,
      subCancelled: 93,
      pastDue: 94,
      monthOn: 81,
    },
    {
      date: '03-29-2021',
      usersReg: 37,
      subscribers: 38,
      subPercent: 47,
      subRenew: 92,
      subCancelled: 30,
      pastDue: 66,
      monthOn: 29,
    },
    {
      date: '03-30-2021',
      usersReg: 74,
      subscribers: 27,
      subPercent: 88,
      subRenew: 77,
      subCancelled: 16,
      pastDue: 99,
      monthOn: 25,
    },
    {
      date: '03-31-2021',
      usersReg: 24,
      subscribers: 77,
      subPercent: 34,
      subRenew: 100,
      subCancelled: 36,
      pastDue: 96,
      monthOn: 28,
    },
    {
      date: '04-01-2021',
      usersReg: 82,
      subscribers: 32,
      subPercent: 59,
      subRenew: 62,
      subCancelled: 77,
      pastDue: 79,
      monthOn: 71,
    },
    {
      date: '04-02-2021',
      usersReg: 55,
      subscribers: 97,
      subPercent: 69,
      subRenew: 45,
      subCancelled: 29,
      pastDue: 100,
      monthOn: 63,
    },
    {
      date: '04-03-2021',
      usersReg: 80,
      subscribers: 81,
      subPercent: 97,
      subRenew: 77,
      subCancelled: 40,
      pastDue: 75,
      monthOn: 19,
    },
    {
      date: '04-04-2021',
      usersReg: 65,
      subscribers: 26,
      subPercent: 31,
      subRenew: 33,
      subCancelled: 42,
      pastDue: 66,
      monthOn: 16,
    },
    {
      date: '04-05-2021',
      usersReg: 74,
      subscribers: 73,
      subPercent: 56,
      subRenew: 97,
      subCancelled: 25,
      pastDue: 62,
      monthOn: 80,
    },
    {
      date: '04-06-2021',
      usersReg: 53,
      subscribers: 21,
      subPercent: 12,
      subRenew: 45,
      subCancelled: 39,
      pastDue: 79,
      monthOn: 17,
    },
    {
      date: '04-07-2021',
      usersReg: 100,
      subscribers: 60,
      subPercent: 16,
      subRenew: 26,
      subCancelled: 20,
      pastDue: 28,
      monthOn: 11,
    },
    {
      date: '04-08-2021',
      usersReg: 40,
      subscribers: 76,
      subPercent: 76,
      subRenew: 33,
      subCancelled: 90,
      pastDue: 49,
      monthOn: 25,
    },
    {
      date: '04-09-2021',
      usersReg: 97,
      subscribers: 79,
      subPercent: 37,
      subRenew: 68,
      subCancelled: 79,
      pastDue: 61,
      monthOn: 45,
    },
    {
      date: '04-10-2021',
      usersReg: 50,
      subscribers: 89,
      subPercent: 67,
      subRenew: 89,
      subCancelled: 87,
      pastDue: 33,
      monthOn: 54,
    },
    {
      date: '04-11-2021',
      usersReg: 45,
      subscribers: 65,
      subPercent: 80,
      subRenew: 68,
      subCancelled: 82,
      pastDue: 67,
      monthOn: 73,
    },
    {
      date: '04-12-2021',
      usersReg: 89,
      subscribers: 45,
      subPercent: 85,
      subRenew: 59,
      subCancelled: 24,
      pastDue: 33,
      monthOn: 95,
    },
    {
      date: '04-13-2021',
      usersReg: 41,
      subscribers: 54,
      subPercent: 74,
      subRenew: 41,
      subCancelled: 22,
      pastDue: 82,
      monthOn: 17,
    },
    {
      date: '04-14-2021',
      usersReg: 15,
      subscribers: 39,
      subPercent: 76,
      subRenew: 16,
      subCancelled: 74,
      pastDue: 27,
      monthOn: 47,
    },
    {
      date: '04-15-2021',
      usersReg: 39,
      subscribers: 57,
      subPercent: 90,
      subRenew: 90,
      subCancelled: 49,
      pastDue: 58,
      monthOn: 73,
    },
    {
      date: '04-16-2021',
      usersReg: 32,
      subscribers: 32,
      subPercent: 61,
      subRenew: 26,
      subCancelled: 73,
      pastDue: 23,
      monthOn: 11,
    },
    {
      date: '04-17-2021',
      usersReg: 23,
      subscribers: 47,
      subPercent: 92,
      subRenew: 33,
      subCancelled: 76,
      pastDue: 84,
      monthOn: 98,
    },
    {
      date: '04-18-2021',
      usersReg: 72,
      subscribers: 89,
      subPercent: 10,
      subRenew: 90,
      subCancelled: 82,
      pastDue: 95,
      monthOn: 60,
    },
    {
      date: '04-19-2021',
      usersReg: 71,
      subscribers: 27,
      subPercent: 78,
      subRenew: 46,
      subCancelled: 75,
      pastDue: 68,
      monthOn: 85,
    },
    {
      date: '04-20-2021',
      usersReg: 59,
      subscribers: 44,
      subPercent: 47,
      subRenew: 20,
      subCancelled: 29,
      pastDue: 26,
      monthOn: 70,
    },
    {
      date: '04-21-2021',
      usersReg: 79,
      subscribers: 79,
      subPercent: 70,
      subRenew: 73,
      subCancelled: 41,
      pastDue: 66,
      monthOn: 73,
    },
    {
      date: '04-22-2021',
      usersReg: 42,
      subscribers: 23,
      subPercent: 78,
      subRenew: 20,
      subCancelled: 24,
      pastDue: 22,
      monthOn: 25,
    },
    {
      date: '04-23-2021',
      usersReg: 34,
      subscribers: 73,
      subPercent: 11,
      subRenew: 59,
      subCancelled: 58,
      pastDue: 22,
      monthOn: 50,
    },
    {
      date: '04-24-2021',
      usersReg: 50,
      subscribers: 39,
      subPercent: 25,
      subRenew: 33,
      subCancelled: 82,
      pastDue: 22,
      monthOn: 52,
    },
    {
      date: '04-25-2021',
      usersReg: 27,
      subscribers: 53,
      subPercent: 76,
      subRenew: 67,
      subCancelled: 45,
      pastDue: 40,
      monthOn: 10,
    },
    {
      date: '04-26-2021',
      usersReg: 96,
      subscribers: 58,
      subPercent: 71,
      subRenew: 32,
      subCancelled: 51,
      pastDue: 98,
      monthOn: 37,
    },
    {
      date: '04-27-2021',
      usersReg: 10,
      subscribers: 31,
      subPercent: 79,
      subRenew: 62,
      subCancelled: 25,
      pastDue: 43,
      monthOn: 80,
    },
    {
      date: '04-28-2021',
      usersReg: 86,
      subscribers: 26,
      subPercent: 25,
      subRenew: 76,
      subCancelled: 18,
      pastDue: 67,
      monthOn: 16,
    },
    {
      date: '04-29-2021',
      usersReg: 58,
      subscribers: 14,
      subPercent: 100,
      subRenew: 56,
      subCancelled: 84,
      pastDue: 75,
      monthOn: 47,
    },
    {
      date: '04-30-2021',
      usersReg: 95,
      subscribers: 65,
      subPercent: 88,
      subRenew: 61,
      subCancelled: 84,
      pastDue: 37,
      monthOn: 47,
    },
    {
      date: '05-01-2021',
      usersReg: 99,
      subscribers: 24,
      subPercent: 77,
      subRenew: 74,
      subCancelled: 37,
      pastDue: 55,
      monthOn: 43,
    },
    {
      date: '05-02-2021',
      usersReg: 85,
      subscribers: 89,
      subPercent: 17,
      subRenew: 41,
      subCancelled: 67,
      pastDue: 47,
      monthOn: 54,
    },
    {
      date: '05-03-2021',
      usersReg: 36,
      subscribers: 89,
      subPercent: 34,
      subRenew: 30,
      subCancelled: 78,
      pastDue: 68,
      monthOn: 22,
    },
    {
      date: '05-04-2021',
      usersReg: 67,
      subscribers: 68,
      subPercent: 46,
      subRenew: 59,
      subCancelled: 50,
      pastDue: 74,
      monthOn: 76,
    },
    {
      date: '05-05-2021',
      usersReg: 18,
      subscribers: 31,
      subPercent: 13,
      subRenew: 81,
      subCancelled: 30,
      pastDue: 54,
      monthOn: 74,
    },
    {
      date: '05-06-2021',
      usersReg: 17,
      subscribers: 91,
      subPercent: 49,
      subRenew: 84,
      subCancelled: 94,
      pastDue: 68,
      monthOn: 57,
    },
  ];



const subscriberChart = am4core.create(
      'subscription-chart',
      am4charts.XYChart
    );

    subscriberChart.data = this.initChartData;

    const categoryAxis = subscriberChart.xAxes.push(
      new am4charts.CategoryAxis()
    );
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = 'date';
    categoryAxis.renderer.opposite = true;
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#03a9f4');

    // Create value axis
    const valueAxis = subscriberChart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
    //valueAxis.title.text = 'Place taken';
    valueAxis.renderer.minLabelPosition = 0.01;

    // Configure grid
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color('#0071a5');
    // Configure labels
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#03a9f4');

    // Create series
    const userRegSeries = subscriberChart.series.push(
      new am4charts.LineSeries()
    );
    const userRegSeriesBulletsColors = '#ffc107';
    userRegSeries.dataFields.valueY = 'usersReg';
    userRegSeries.dataFields.categoryX = 'date';
    userRegSeries.name = 'Registered Users';
    userRegSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    userRegSeries.tooltipText = '{valueY} {name} in {categoryX}';
    userRegSeries.legendSettings.valueText = '{valueY}';
    userRegSeries.stroke = am4core.color(userRegSeriesBulletsColors);

    const subscribersSeries = subscriberChart.series.push(
      new am4charts.LineSeries()
    );
    const subscribersSeriesBulletsColors = '#00b301';
    subscribersSeries.dataFields.valueY = 'subscribers';
    subscribersSeries.dataFields.categoryX = 'date';
    subscribersSeries.name = 'Subscribers';
    subscribersSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    subscribersSeries.tooltipText = '{valueY} {name} in {categoryX}';
    subscribersSeries.legendSettings.valueText = '{valueY}';
    subscribersSeries.stroke = am4core.color(subscribersSeriesBulletsColors);

    const subPercentSeries = subscriberChart.series.push(
      new am4charts.LineSeries()
    );

    const subPercentSeriesBulletsColors = '#00bcd4';
    subPercentSeries.dataFields.valueY = 'subPercent';
    subPercentSeries.dataFields.categoryX = 'date';
    subPercentSeries.name = 'Subscriber Percentage';
    subPercentSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
    subPercentSeries.tooltipText = '{valueY} {name} in {categoryX}';
    subPercentSeries.legendSettings.valueText = '{valueY}';
    subPercentSeries.stroke = am4core.color(subPercentSeriesBulletsColors);

    // Add chart cursor
    subscriberChart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
    subscriberChart.cursor.behavior = 'zoomY';

    let hs1 = userRegSeries.segments.template.states.create('hover');
    hs1.properties.strokeWidth = 5;
    userRegSeries.segments.template.strokeWidth = 1;
    userRegSeries.properties.fill = am4core.color(userRegSeriesBulletsColors);

    let hs2 = subscribersSeries.segments.template.states.create('hover');
    hs2.properties.strokeWidth = 5;
    subscribersSeries.segments.template.strokeWidth = 1;
    subscribersSeries.properties.fill = am4core.color(
      subscribersSeriesBulletsColors
    );

    let hs3 = subPercentSeries.segments.template.states.create('hover');
    hs3.properties.strokeWidth = 5;
    subPercentSeries.segments.template.strokeWidth = 1;
    subPercentSeries.properties.fill = am4core.color(
      subPercentSeriesBulletsColors
    );

    // Add legend
    subscriberChart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

    subscriberChart.legend.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#252525');
    subscriberChart.legend.valueLabels.template.fill = am4core.color('#252525');
```

```css
#subscription-chart{
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

<div id="subscription-chart" class="subscription-chart"></div>
```